# How do I set the -target parameter for package installs in OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, gcc

I am trying to install [the `osx-gcc-installer`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) for 10.7.

I want to install it with the `installer` command.

The `installer` command requires a -target parameter and it is the part I am not sure about.

1. Is there any convention for target location for this kind of pkg file ('developer tools')? /opt or /etc/ or /var?
2. Is there an uninstall counterpart to `installer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the manpage of `installer`. The `-target` option does *not* specify a directory, but an actual volume (emphasis mine):

> The **target volume** is specified with the `-target` parameter ( `-tgt` is accepted as a synonym).  It must already be mounted when the installer command is invoked.

So, just run it, specifying your boot volume:

```
installer -pkg GCC-10.7.pkg -target /
```

I guess that should be enough. A package installer knows where to put its files.

---

> Is there an uninstall counterpart to installer?

Not really. Every package installer also creates a so-called "receipt" which contains a list of those files that were installed. This receipt is mostly used for repairing permissions, but can also (theoretically) be used to "undo" package installations.

These receipt files are located in:

- `/var/db/receipts` starting with OS X 10.6.
- `/Library/Receipts/db` or `~/Library/Receipts/db/` in OS X 10.5 (but here, it's an Sqlite database)
- `/Library/Receipts` in OS X 10.4

Using the `lsbom` command, you can list the contents of such a receipt file.

```
lsbom -fls /var/db/receipts/some.receipt.bom
```

This gives you a list of files. If you need to, you can *try* to remove all of these files. But I have never seen somebody really encourage that. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: The target can also be specified as just `-target /` (instead of `"/Volumes/Macintosh HD"`). Some people have renamed the boot volume.

Comment: True that. It was even mentioned in the manpage.